# How Am I Botching PLINQ? (Parallelizing Simple/Fast Computations)

Tags: c#, simulation, plinq

I'm trying to use PLINQ to speed up a simple simulation, but I'm managing to slow it down instead (uncommented AsParallel runs slower):

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> GetNextPair(int pairs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs; i++)
            yield return new Tuple<double, double>(Random.NextDouble(), Random.NextDouble());
    }

    private static double RunSimPlinq(int count)
    {
        return
            GetNextPair(count)
                //.ToArray()
                //.AsParallel()
                .Count(tuple =>
                    {
                        //Thread.Sleep(10);
                        return tuple.Item1*tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2*tuple.Item2 <= 1d;
                    })*4d/count;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(RunSimPlinq(100));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

My only guess as to the reason is contention on the enumerable of rands (or, on the contrary, copying of it).

PS. The output should be an estimate of PI.

Comment: If you fill an array and use that instead of GetNextPair(), does it make much difference? It might be buffering because of the yield.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I can't see any AsParallel()

Comment: @Aron You don't see the line that reads `//.AsParallel()`?

Comment: @svick ah there it is...

Comment: FYI, `Random` isn't thread safe.  It doesn't matter here, but if you cared about what the results were, and not how fast it ran, then it would matter.

Comment: @Servy in an earlier attempt, I was calling into it directly instead of wrapping in an iterator -- I decided to wrap it after seeing that it didn't converge on 3.14 even with 100M runs

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- I tried `GetNextPair(count).ToArray()` with and without `AsParallel()`; in both cases it slowed it down, but didn't reverse the interaction; the PLINQ version still ran slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Plinq has quite a large amount of overhead. Its very useful for computationally intensive projections, what you have IS NOT computationally intensive.

<strike>Firstly. PLinq will NOT parallelize the GetNextPair part of the linq query. You can try placing a break point into that function and bringing up the Thread window to check which thread is running it each time.</strike>

Secondly the part that IS actually parallelised is the

```
.Count(tuple => tuple.Item1*tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2*tuple.Item2 <= 1d)
```

part, which is basically

```
.Where(tuple => tuple.Item1*tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2*tuple.Item2 <= 1d)
.Count()
```

The where part is going to work quite easily. However, the dispatching to each thread to run the predicate is going to have quite an overhead.

The count part then would require a map reduce, again, could have quite an overhead.

So the only way you could have a speed up is if the predicate is computationally more intensive than the overhead of scheduling the predicate and then map reducing the result.

Try whacking in a Thread.Sleep into the predicate...

Comment: as far as the overhead tipping the scales, you're right -- `Thread.Sleep()` in the predicate showed it. However, the `GetNextPair()` method _is_ getting called from many worker threads (which certainly makes me feel better about the whole thing).

Comment: @nik.shornikov Even if it is called from multiple threads, it won't be called from multiple threads *at the same time*, so that part of the query won't be parallelized.

Comment: @svick I put the sleep in the iterator, and I can see that now (only one worker thread ever in there); I suppose this is both good and bad; the good being that the `IEnumerable` doesn't need to be thread-safe